# Revealing Module Pattern - Global variables / Init function

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I want to finally get rid of my unstructured way of writing JS and red a lot about the "Revealing Module Pattern" lately. At least to me it seems pretty usefull, but I haven't found answers to some of my questions yet. So let's say we have some different modules in our JS, in this case "site" and "nav". The "nav" module has some private functions in it and probably some public ones as well later on. What's the best way of calling the init function in those modules. I thought of creating a public function for them and then calling them with `MODULE.init()`;. But to me this seems like bad practice and I haven't seen it anywhere before.

```
$(function () {
    var site = (function () {
        var 
            module = {},
            privateVar = 3; // private variable

        function privateFunction() { // private function
            // some code here
        }

        module.init = function () {
           // global init function
        };        

        return module;
    }());

    var nav = (function () {
        var 
            module = {},
            navOpen = false; // private variable

        function open() { // private function
            // some code here
        }
        function close() { // private function
            // some code here
        }

        module.init = function () {                    
            // event handlers for open and close functions etc.
        };        

        return module;
    }());

    nav.init();
    site.init();

});
```

Another question, which I didn't find in any of the articles I red was how to define a global variable (like body), which I probably need in any of my modules (adding some classes to it or something). So let's say I need access to my `body` (like so in jQuery `$("body")`) in both the "nav" and "site" module. Is it better to do it like that:

```
$(function () {
    var site = (function () {
        var 
            module = {},
            body = $("body"); // creating the "body" variable in every module

        // .. module code
        return module;
    }());

    var nav = (function () {
        var 
            module = {},
            body = $("body"); // and again in this module

        // module code       
        return module;
    }());

});
```

or to have it at the very top of your JS file

```
$(function () {
    var
        body = $("body");

    var site = (function () {
        // module code
    }());

    var nav = (function () {
        // module code
    }());
```

Or is there any better way to do it / to improve my code in general? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't put a newline after var alone. Looks ugly and ASI may break your things

Comment: @lukas.pukenis Thanks, will do. What about the init function or the global "body" variable. Any suggestion, how to deal with it?

Comment: @demrks You'll get access of body variables thanks to Closure.

Comment: @ClaudioSantos Thanks, but could you give me a quick example please? I#m new to all this stuff and I'm not quite sure, how to get "access" to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get access of body variables thanks to Closure, the [example here](http://jsbin.com/AyADAtu/2/edit?html,js,console,output).

So, you don't need to declare some body variable inside your functions.

For the constructor issue, you already have one, is the function that you use to declare your object, see this example for [detailed example](http://jsbin.com/AyADAtu/3/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: Ah okay thanks. To me your example looks similar to my third code snippet, so i assume that is the best way to do it. Do you have any suggestions for the other question i had regarding the "init" function? At the moment i declare the "init" function public and then calling it like "MODULE.init()" (see first code snippet in my answer). But to me that seems wrong or bad practice somehow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Finaly an example with my suggestion with constructor, see the update.